# comment a block of code in ISE powerShell editor

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, csom

I have to comment the block of code with short-cut keys.
How to comment a block of code in ISE powerShell editor for CSOM for SharePoint ps1 files?? or is there any manual way except write manually # to every line.

Comment: Refer https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj984298.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark the lines which you want to comment with Alt+Shift+Up/Down and then press '#'. To uncomment hit 'Backspace'. A nice undocumented feature :)

Or use:

```
<# #>
```

Comment: Thanks Paul Strupeikis !!
Its worked, but occured new errors as -

Answer (score 2):

I have never tried any short cut keys for this but, there is certainly a way to comment a block of code.

```
<#
$site = 'http://yoursite' 
$credentials = Get-Credential
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($site)
#>
```